# Live validating and outputting a text field with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate and return a textbox input field bu using

```
var ok = phNum.search(/^\(?\d{3}\D*\d{3}\D*\d{4}$/);
if (ok==0) {
  var parts = phNum.match(/^\(?(\d{3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{4})$/);
  output.value='('+parts[1]+') '+parts[2]+'-'+parts[3];
}
```

which is supposed to accept: 555-555-1234, 5555551234, (555) 555-1234, etc. and return: (555) 555-1234 at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/hza0wex5/).

Here is the code I have

```
<input id='phone'></input>

<script>
 $("#phone").on("load change keyup paste", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8) {} else {
        var output;
        var input = $("#phone").val();

        $("#phone").val(output);

        var ok = phNum.search(/^\(?\d{3}\D*\d{3}\D*\d{4}$/);
        if (ok == 0) {
            var parts = phNum.match(/^\(?(\d{3})\D*(\d{3})\D*(\d{4})$/);
            output.value = '(' + parts[1] + ') ' + parts[2] + '-' + parts[3];
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

but I am not getting the result back! Why is this happening and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of javascript, you could use the browsers built in regex pattern matcher:

```
<input id='phone' pattern="/^\(?\d{3}\D*\d{3}\D*\d{4}$/"></input>
```

and..... "output" is not defined:

```
var output;
```

Then you use it:

```
$("#phone").val(output); //What's the value of "output" here? : undefined
```

Plus.... if you check the input every time you change its value, you will be checking it also when you type the first number. That will not match your regex, so it removes it....

Edit:

Check this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/hza0wex5/5/
It will only format the number if the input has at least 10 characters

Comment: Hi DevPGSV and thanks for reply, I updated the code here http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/hza0wex5/2/ but still not getting result?

Comment: Thanks  DevPGSV , just can you also let me know how to limit the size of input ? I maen after 10 number?

Comment: One more thing: http://jsfiddle.net/DevPGSV/rp1wocuy/4/

XDDD
(Just check if some A to Z letters are in the input, if found, reset)